# Compatible RSA padding encryption between objective c and Java

Tags: java, ios, encryption, rsa, padding

I read a lot of references ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526452/difference-between-pkcs1-padding-rsa-encryption-ios-objc-and-java) ,[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340704/java-to-objective-c-rsa-implementation), etc... ) but without any result:

The process works as below:

1- Server (web-service) generates AES key.

2- Then Server encrypts this key with RSA as the below Java code.

3- Client side (iOS and/or Android) decrypts AES key in RSA using below objective-c code.

4- Client side encrypts this AES key again with RSA as below objective-c code, and send to server.

**The problem:**

> This code works fine a lot of times, and sometimes give me (after server receives data from client) invalid AES key size (different numbers)

My Java code: (Server)

```
public static byte[] encryptWithRSA(byte[] data,PublicKey clientKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Start encryptWithRSA ");
        Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding", "BC");
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clientKey);
        cipherText = encrypt.doFinal(data); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage);
        throw ex;
    }
    return cipherText;
}

public static byte[] decryptWithRSA(byte[] encryptedMessage,PrivateKey serverKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] decryptedMessage = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Start decryptWithRSA ");
        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding", "BC");
        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, serverKey);
        decryptedMessage = decrypt.doFinal(encryptedMessage);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage);
        throw ex;
    }
    return decryptedMessage;
}
```

My iOS code, (client side):
(I'm using [this RSA implementation](https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA) )

```
// Encrypt with RSA

- (NSData *)encryptData:(NSData *)data withKeyRef:(SecKeyRef) keyRef{
const uint8_t *srcbuf = (const uint8_t *)[data bytes];
size_t srclen = (size_t)data.length;

size_t block_size = SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef) * sizeof(uint8_t);
void *outbuf = malloc(block_size);
size_t src_block_size = block_size - 11;

NSMutableData *ret = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
for(int idx=0; idx<srclen; idx+=src_block_size){
    //NSLog(@"%d/%d block_size: %d", idx, (int)srclen, (int)block_size);
    size_t data_len = srclen - idx;
    if(data_len > src_block_size){
        data_len = src_block_size;
    }

    size_t outlen = block_size;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    status = SecKeyEncrypt(keyRef,
                           kSecPaddingNone, //kSecPaddingPKCS1  "I updated the padding to be none" 
                           srcbuf + idx,
                           data_len,
                           outbuf,
                           &outlen
                           );
    if (status != 0) {
        NSLog(@"SecKeyEncrypt fail. Error Code: %d", status);
        ret = nil;
        break;
    }else{
        [ret appendBytes:outbuf length:outlen];
    }
}

free(outbuf);
CFRelease(keyRef);
return ret;
}

// Decrypt with RSA

- (NSData *)decryptData:(NSData *)data withKeyRef:(SecKeyRef) keyRef{
const uint8_t *srcbuf = (const uint8_t *)[data bytes];
size_t srclen = (size_t)data.length;

size_t block_size = SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef) * sizeof(uint8_t);
UInt8 *outbuf = malloc(block_size);
size_t src_block_size = block_size;

NSMutableData *ret = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
for(int idx=0; idx<srclen; idx+=src_block_size){
    //NSLog(@"%d/%d block_size: %d", idx, (int)srclen, (int)block_size);
    size_t data_len = srclen - idx;
    if(data_len > src_block_size){
        data_len = src_block_size;
    }

    size_t outlen = block_size;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    status = SecKeyDecrypt(keyRef,
                           kSecPaddingNone ,    
                           srcbuf + idx,
                           data_len,
                           outbuf,
                           &outlen
                           );
    if (status != 0) {
        NSLog(@"SecKeyEncrypt fail. Error Code: %d", status);
        ret = nil;
        break;
    }else{
        //the actual decrypted data is in the middle, locate it!
        int idxFirstZero = -1;
        int idxNextZero = (int)outlen;
        for ( int i = 0; i < outlen; i++ ) {
            if ( outbuf[i] == 0 ) {
                if ( idxFirstZero < 0 ) {
                    idxFirstZero = i;
                } else {
                    idxNextZero = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [ret appendBytes:&outbuf[idxFirstZero+1] length:idxNextZero-idxFirstZero-1];
    }
}

free(outbuf);
CFRelease(keyRef);
return ret;
}
```

Thanks for paying attention ...

Comment: Why not just use https?

Comment: I'm using wildfly 10 server, so can I call web service with https using it ?

Comment: First google hit http://reallifejava.com/configuring-ssl-in-wildfly-8/ and im sure there are more. Implementing your own encryption (very badly) both wastes your time and doesn't provide you any security. Just use a standard protocol that already encrypts for you.